When to use Span<T> versus Marshal when calling native Win32 APIs?
I need to call a Win32 API which spits out a null terminated string into a buffer, and then read that string from the buffer.
I've recently learned about Span<T>, and I'm trying to figure out whether I should be using it, or doing things the traditional way using the Marshal class.
Below you will see two different ways of acheiving the same goal, one using Span<T> and the other using Marshal.
What I want to know is, is my use of Span<T> sensible here? And would the performance be the same or better when using Span<T>?
And as a side note, is there a "more correct" way to extract a null terminated string from a Span<byte>, or is the way I'm doing it fine?
Using Marshal:
[DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool HidD_GetProductString(IntPtr HidDeviceObject, IntPtr Buffer, uint BufferLength);

public static string GetProductNameUsingMarshal(IntPtr handle)
{

    var stringPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(254);

    try
    {
        if (!Win32.HidD_GetProductString(handle, stringPtr, 254)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastPInvokeError(), Marshal.GetLastPInvokeErrorMessage());
        }

        return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(stringPtr);
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(stringPtr);
    }

}

Using Span:
[DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool HidD_GetProductString(IntPtr HidDeviceObject, ref byte Buffer, uint BufferLength);

public static string GetProductNameUsingSpan(IntPtr handle)
{

    var buffer = new Span<byte>(new byte[254]);

    var success = Win32.HidD_GetProductString(handle, ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(buffer), 254);

    if (!success)
    {
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastPInvokeError(), Marshal.GetLastPInvokeErrorMessage());
    }

    var charSpan = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, char>(buffer);

    return new string(charSpan.Slice(0, charSpan.IndexOf(char.MinValue)));

}


Why are you doing any of that instead of passing an [Out] string Buffer?

[DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool HidD_GetProductString(IntPtr HidDeviceObject, [Out] out string Buffer, uint BufferLength);
var success = Win32.HidD_GetProductString(handle, out var thestring, 254);
System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

[Out] string Buffer, not [Out] out string Buffer.

Tried that first, same result.

Did you allocate memory in that string before calling (make it have the 254 characters)? Alternatively, StringBuilder Buffer, and pass a StringBuilder with Capacity of 254.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1838
Avoid StringBuilder parameters for P/Invokes

There is not a huge difference between the two. Marshal is older, but in some ways safer for PInvoke as it doesn't mess with the managed heap. Span can be better in many ways, as it allows you to directly handle the buffers without copying, and to assign it to a normal byte[] array on the managed heap.
Whatever you do, do not cast the ref to a * pointer or you will get a GC hole (GC cannot track * pointers and may move or overwrite the buffer).
But both of these are unnecessary. You can pass a byte[] buffer directly.
[DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool HidD_GetProductString(IntPtr HidDeviceObject, [Out] byte[] Buffer, uint BufferLength);

public static string GetProductNameUsingSpan(IntPtr handle)
{
    var buffer = new byte[254];
    var success = Win32.HidD_GetProductString(handle, buffer, buffer.Length);
    if (!success)
    {
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastPInvokeError(), Marshal.GetLastPInvokeErrorMessage());
    }

    var charSpan = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, char>(buffer.AsSpan());
    return new string(charSpan.Slice(0, charSpan.IndexOf(char.MinValue)));
}

Note that 254 is the number of bytes, you only get half as many characters as it's UTF16 (and subtract 1 for the NUL terminator).
For other functions which return ANSI, casting directly to char is flat wrong. You need to use Encoding.ASCII.GetString to re-encode it.
